# How to delay a boolean signal in Modelica?

Tags: boolean, delay, modelica

Seems like the delay block only accepts a real input/output. I can't find anything on a boolean delay. Or do I need to do a boolean to real conversion?

I am very new to Modelica, but this seems like an obvious built-in block to me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you model it using `delay()`, do note that the signal may be interpolated. So you would have to decide if `0.5` was `true` or `false`.

You can however implement your own (slightly inefficient) delay-buffer (tested in OpenModelica and Dymola):

```
model M
  parameter Integer bufferSize = 10;
  parameter Real delayTime = 0.1;
  discrete Real nextTime[bufferSize](each start = 0);
  Boolean delayBuffer[bufferSize](each start = false);
  Boolean signal,delayed;
  Integer n(start = 0), m(start = 1), prem;
equation
  when change(signal) then
    n = if pre(n)==10 then 1 else pre(n)+1;
    nextTime = {if i<>n then pre(nextTime[i]) else time + delayTime for i in 1:bufferSize};
    delayBuffer = {if i<>n then pre(delayBuffer[i]) else signal for i in 1:bufferSize};
  end when;
equation
  prem = pre(m);
  when time > nextTime[pre(m)] then
    delayed = delayBuffer[pre(m)];
    m = if pre(m)==10 then 1 else pre(m)+1;
  end when;
  if time < 0.1 then
    signal = true;
  elseif time < 0.2 then
    signal = false;
  elseif time < 0.7 then
    signal = true;
  elseif time < 0.71 then
    signal = false;
  elseif time < 0.72 then
    signal = true;
  elseif time < 0.73 then
    signal = false;
  elseif time < 0.74 then
    signal = true;
  elseif time < 0.75 then
    signal = false;
  else
    signal = true;
  end if;
end M;
```

The results are wrong until after the first signal has been delayed, but it can probably be improved. The if-statement for `signal` is just a sample signal for testing.